Unable to import workspace/package within gatsby-config.ts
I have a monorepo, with private packages. There is MAIN, and a package-mini.
Main package is widely using package-mini across the components this with no error as:
import { foo } from "@workspace/package-mini";
But, when I do the same within gatsby-config.ts I get build errors like: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'A' before initialization.
The ugly workaround is just to use a relative path since my packages are private are in the same repo:
import { foo } from "../package-mini";
I'm reading in Gatsby Docs that workspaces are not supported. Is that referring to the config so there is basically no other choices? I tried setting alias but no difference.
